# Когда я указал путь к гугл драйверами библиотеке selenium выдало ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

URL = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFcFbwy_gxU3rIMJ-AF5HgQ/videos"

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Users\Bubunduc\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\google driver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(URL)
```

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю проблема в том, что python не может декодировать `"\"`.

Попробуй так:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Bubunduc\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\google driver\chromedriver.exe')
```

Или так

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Bubunduc/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/google driver/chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: Умеет, но в той строке было `\Users`, т.е. последовательность, начинающиеся с `\U` а так описываются последовательности для юникодных символов

Comment: оба варианта рабочие, спасибо